# Selenium doesn't run with default profile

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable /dev/shm usage
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pcped\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

When I run chromedriver, without headless mode, using my default profile I get this error
Also before it crashes, it does open a correct chrome window with the intended profile logged in.

```
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x002EA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0027C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00185358]
    (No symbol) [0x001A3621]
    (No symbol) [0x001A0579]
    (No symbol) [0x001D0C55]
    (No symbol) [0x001D093C]
    (No symbol) [0x001CA536]
    (No symbol) [0x001A82DC]
    (No symbol) [0x001A93DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0054AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0058456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x003751E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00285F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00282328]
    (No symbol) [0x0028240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00274FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76F07D59+25]
    RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77A2B74B+107]
    RtlClearBits [0x77A2B6CF+191]
    (No symbol) [0x00000000]
```

When I run it without my profile, it runs without headless mode as intended.
When I run it in headless mode using the profile, the code doesn't work as if my profile is being used (need it for login credentials)

So why can I run it without headless mode or with profile, but not both at the same time?

Already tried adding the profile this way instead but it didn't work:

```
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Run Chrome in headless mode
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable /dev/shm usage
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pcped\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```